# Using public data for dynamic data

Tags: angularjs, chart.js, angular-chart

Hi I'm trying to use the google public data for building a demo chart using angular and chartjs. I have created a http request inside the controller and trying to view the  fetched data in the console, in-order to see what data are available. But Im getting an error `$http.get(...).success is not a function`,What does it mean and how to overcome this and display the data. Also Im getting `XHR finished loading: GET` what does it mean ? . Thank you :)

[Link to sample data !!!](https://www.google.com/publicdata/explore?ds=z8o7pt6rd5uqa6_&ctype=l&strail=false&bcs=d&nselm=h&met_y=unemployment&fdim_y=age_group:y_lt25&fdim_y=seasonality:sa&scale_y=lin&ind_y=false&rdim=country_group&idim=country_group:non-eu&idim=country:de&ifdim=country_group&ind=false&icfg)

```
myApp.controller('chartController',function($scope,$http){
    $http.get("https://www.google.com/publicdata/explore?ds=z8o7pt6rd5uqa6_&ctype=l&strail=false&bcs=d&nselm=h&met_y=unemployment&fdim_y=age_group:y_lt25&fdim_y=seasonality:sa&scale_y=lin&ind_y=false&rdim=country_group&idim=country_group:non-eu&idim=country:de&ifdim=country_group&ind=false&icfg")
    .success(function(data,response){
    console.log(data);
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Angular 1.6+, `.success` [has been removed (it has been deprecated since 1.5)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35329384/why-are-angular-http-success-error-methods-deprecated-removed-from-v1-6). Use [`.then`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) instead:

```
$http.get("https://www.google.com/publicdata/explore?ds=z8o7pt6rd5uqa6_&ctype=l&strail=false&bcs=d&nselm=h&met_y=unemployment&fdim_y=age_group:y_lt25&fdim_y=seasonality:sa&scale_y=lin&ind_y=false&rdim=country_group&idim=country_group:non-eu&idim=country:de&ifdim=country_group&ind=false&icfg")
.then(function(response){
    console.log(response.data);
})
```